# How to make a menu re-appear in java

Tags: java, menu

```
import java.util.*;
public class LabTest1
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        double Choice1;
        double Choice2;
        int MenuChoice;
        System.out.print("Please enter the length: ");
        Choice1 = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Please enter the width: ");
        Choice2 = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("=============================");
        System.out.println("|   MENU SELECTION          |");
        System.out.println("=============================");
        System.out.println("| Options:                  |");
        System.out.println("| 1. Calculate the area     |");
        System.out.println("| 2. Calculate the perimeter|");
        System.out.println("| 3. Exit                   |");
        System.out.println("=============================");
        MenuChoice = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" Select option: ");

    switch (MenuChoice)
    {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Calculate the area selected");   
        System.out.println(Choice1 * Choice2);
        break;
    case 2:
      System.out.println(" Calculate the perimeter selected");  
      System.out.println(2*(Choice1 + Choice2));
      break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Exit selected");
        System.out.println(Choice1 + Choice2);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        break; 
    }

    }
}
```

I need to make it so if the values are equal it should display a message saying that the values represent a square and allow the user to re-enter the values untill appropriate vlaues are entered ( yes i know a square is a rectangle)

Comment: Put the code the show the menu and read the input in a function and call it where you want to display it again

Comment: I'm sorry @iTech I'm kinda new at this can you explaine a little bit more please?

Comment: This looks like an assignment to me, so I won't give you the exact answer. Just take the code from the `main` function above the `switch` statement and put it to a new static function. Then call it from the main function within a loop that check if the input is valid or no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pattern to ask for input, reject invalid input and loop:

```
boolean isValidInput = false;
[print prompt for input]
while (!isValidInput) {
   input = ...
   if (input is not valid) {
       print [invalid input, what is right form]
   } else {
       isValidInput = true;
   }
 }
```

By the way, you should use the minimum text possible.  Print the request and what you are doing once, and the prompt for bad input each time they enter wrong information.

Comment: Where should i add this? I am just a starter so all of this is new to me. Sorry

Comment: COnsider what things look like to your user. It looks like you want to start by asking the user to enter the dimensions of a non-square rectangle and then accept the length and width.  If the length and width represent a square prompt the user and loop (get length and width in the while loop)